# Can you help me identify the set?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

These pieces are part of a large box I received and I am thinking they belong to a Star Wars set, but I have searched fruitlessly and haven't found which one.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Top left:

[Darth Maul's Sith Infiltrator 7961-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7961-1)

[image: set image]

## Top Right:

[ARC-170 Starfighter 8088-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8088-1&name=ARC-170%20Starfighter&category=%5BStar%20Wars%5D%5BStar%20Wars%20Clone%20Wars%5D#T=I)

[image: set image]

## Bottom Left:

[Sith Nightspeeder 7957-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7957-1#T=I)

[image: set image]

## Bottom Right:

[One of 3 Alpha Team: Mission Deep Freeze sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47844pb01&in=S). I think it's [Ice Blade 4743-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4743-1#T=I), if that's the same sticker I see on the side.

## Bottom Center:

[No direct matches](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=58846&in=S), but appears to be a sticker from a [Hyena Droid Bomber 8016-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8016-1#T=I) on the wrong color of piece.